# Is it possible to change what Permissions are the "Ask For"-Permissions in Firefox/LibreWolf?

Tags: firefox, permissions

I used Brave for a while, but then I came back to Firefox and today I switched to a Firefox-Fork called "LibreWolf", but I miss something I had on Brave: The ability to choose for which permissions Websites have to ask.

On Firefox, all Permissions have the Options "always allow" and "always deny", but some (e.g. camera, mic, location, etc...) have a third option called "always ask". And that is a great Idea, because "Always allow Microphone" would be a horrible Idea, but "Always deny Microphone" would make you go crazy on Skype or other Video-Conferencing tools.

But is it possible to change the Mode of some other Permissions to "Always ask"? Because it seems like "JavaScript" does not have the "always ask" option, although I would like to have JS as "always ask", because the Browser-native Permission System
should be better than an Extension like NoScript (and it would definitely save storage/memory since it is part of Firefox and must not be downloaded separately)

On Brave I had "JavaScript" as an "Always ask" Permission, and it worked fine, how can I do this in Firefox/Librewolf, and if I can't, I would like to know what I would need to change in the source code of Firefox, because I might fork it then .(yes, I might do this, I want to have this feature)

On about:preferences#privacy I scroll down to "Permissions" and it only displays the default Permissions.

I remember that some time ago, I saw more Permissions by clicking on some button I can't find anymore (maybe my memory is wrong) but most of them only had permanent allow/deny and no "ask" Option.

I was expecting to see JavaScript as a permission (at least in LibreWolf) and I would like to set it to "always ask" or see that as the default.